# Simple checkbox test with vue unit testing library

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vitest, vue-testing-library

Trying to work out something that I thought would be pretty simple!

I have a PrimeVue checkbox component on my page (and I'm using Vue 3, PrimeVue, vitest, @testing-library/vue and @testing-library/user-event)

```
<div class="field-checkbox">
    <Checkbox role = "checkbox" :aria-label="`Select all students in class ${props.className}`" @change="selectAllChecked()" v-model="selectAll" :binary="true" />
    <label>Select All</label>
</div>
```

I just want to write a test to check the checkbox and then test that it is correctly checked - not a particularly meaningful test but I'm new to these libraries (and unit testing) so want to work out how to do this stuff.

In my test I have:

```
it("checkbox test", async() => {
    const ariaLabel = `Select all students in class ${mockProps.className}`;
    const checkbox = screen.getByRole("checkbox", { name: ariaLabel });
    await userEvent.click(checkbox);
    expect(checkbox.getAttribute('checked')).toBe(true)
});
```

**if I remove the 3rd and 4th lines, the test passes so it seems to be checking that the checkbox is there ok.**

Lines 3 and 4 (I hoped) would allow me to confirm that the checkbox is now checked but my test fails with

```
AssertionError: expected null to be true // Object.is equality
  - Expected   "true"
  + Received   "null"
```

on the 4th line

Comment: Can you share the frontend code?

Comment: I've edited the post with the checkbox markup.  Like I said the test passes ok in terms of finding the checkbox, it's just the clicking it and checking it's value I'm having trouble with.  The Checkbox is a PrimeVue Checkbox component - I'm wondering now if that's the issue?

Comment: One issue I've had in general with checkboxes and other inputs using Vuetify and Cypress, is that if I add a testid to it and try to click it directly like you do, then it doesn't work. I'm not entirely familiar with `@testing-library/vue`, but is there anyway you could try clicking the `parent` of that?

Short explanation on the problem in Cypress + Vuetify can be found [here](https://concentrationcode.com/testing-vuetify-checkbox), not sure if it helps

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what I'm doing wrong, I'm not injecting the PrimeVue plugin to the test and also specifying the CheckBox component in the components:   I will do some more tests and see how I get on